# grep with wildcards

Tags: grep, wildcard

I would like to grep for the following strings in a file:

```
directory1
directory2
directory3
```

Is there a way to grep for all 3 simultaneously with grep?

For instance:

```
cat file.txt | grep directory[1-3]
```

Unfortunately, the above doesn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If those are the only strings you need to search for, use `-F` (grep for fixed strings):

```
grep -F "directory1
directory2
directory3" file.txt
```

If you want to grep using more advanced regex, use `-E` (use extended regex):

```
grep -E 'directory[1-3]' file.txt
```

Note that some `grep`s (like GNU grep) won't require `-E` for this example to work.

Finally, note that you need to quote the regex. If you don't, your shell is liable to expand the regex according to pathname expansion first (e.g. if you have a file/directory called "directory1" in the current directory, `grep directory[1-3]` will be turned into `grep directory1` by your shell).

Answer (score 2):

under which shell did you test?

here

`grep directory[1-3]` works for bash, doesn't work under zsh

you can either quote `"directory[1-3]"`

or escape `grep directory\[1-3\]`

```
bash v4.2
zsh v5.0.2
grep (GNUgrep 2.14)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very pretty but you can chain the grep together:

```
grep -l "directory1" ./*.txt|xargs grep -l "directory2"|xargs grep -l "directory3"
```

Limit your input so to improve performance, for example use find:

```
find ./*.txt -type f |xargs grep -l "directory1"|xargs grep -l "directory2"|xargs grep -l "directory3"
```